# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryUtils.getDefaultRetryPolicy

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to import mySql data to Hadoop using sqoop.
Environment:
Ubuntu 16.04
Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.16.1
Sqoop 1.4.7

On executing

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/crawl_data_stats 
             --username root --password password --table auth_group
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryUtils.getDefaultRetryPolicy(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/retry/RetryPolicy;  
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNNProxyWithClientProtocol(NameNodeProxies.java:408)  
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:314)  
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:176)  
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:763)  
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:694)  
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:159)  
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3303)  
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)  
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)  
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)  
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)  
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:227)  
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:463)  
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)  
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(FileOutputFormat.java:160)  
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.configureOutputFormat(ImportJobBase.java:160)  
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:263)  
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:692)  
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:127)  
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:520)  
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:628)  
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)  
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)  
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)  
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)  
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)  
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

Comment: NoSuchMethodError indicates incompatible jar versions

Comment: Thanks @Jens.  Could you please let me know which jar file is incompatible and where it is located